# Compiling Perl in Vim with quickfix

Tags: perl, vim

Ok, it's not about compiling exactly, but recently I discovered the `:compiler` command in Vim. The help is included in the quickfix documentation, and as fas as I understood I could run:

```
:compiler perl
```

To select the perl interpreter. Then, the help says:

> The Perl compiler plugin doesn't actually compile, but invokes Perl's internal
>     syntax checking feature and parses the output for possible errors so you can
>     correct them in quick-fix mode.

But as it's unclear what should I to actually run the program. May I run `:make`, even without a make file? That makes sense to me, since:

```
echo &makeprg
```

Returns `perl -Wc %`. However…

Doing that on a bogus test program, only returns the standard errors formatting output, no quickfix window is opened. What am I missing here?

Comment: good question posing. thanks for supplying details of what you know and what you tried

Comment: @sehe: Well, thank you for answering it! I just did my duty of researching before simply asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just open the quickfix window with

```
:copen
```

Navigate errors with

```
:crew
:cnext
:cprev
```

---

Note that a common trap with quickfixing using a *non-project* make (i.e. where the makeprg variable usually includes the name of the current buffer (expansion of `%`)), is that when the focus is on the quickfix window, issueing `:make` again will fail, because the quickfix buffer has no filename associated with it. *Perhaps this could be fixed by supplying an artificial name for the quickfix window in e.g. the Perl compiler mode for vim?*

Comment: Ahh, obviously if I want to see the quickfix window, I have to open it. About the `%` expansion, thanks for pointing it out. Indeed, what first came to my mind was including something in `…/compilers/perl.vim`, but I think it would not be possible to name the quickfix window. I tried passing `#` to make as argument, as apparently looks like the `%` expands to nothing, but that didn't work either. It says "Nothing to be done for {perlfile}".

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code, and F6 can run perl script and shown at quickfix.

```
func! checkPerlSyntax()
    let map = &makeprg
    let ef = &errorformat
    let exeFile = expand("%:t")
    setlocal makeprg=perl
    set efm=%C\ %.%#,%A\ \ File\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l%.%#,%Z%[%^\ ]%\\@=%m
    silent make %
    copen
    let &makeprg     = mp
    let &errorformat = ef
endfunc

nmap pl :!perl %<.pl<CR>
map <F6> :call checkPerlSyntax()<CR>
```